# Symfony2 - form global validation not working if validation group is defined

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I found, that my validation for textarea is not working, if I'm not logged. If am I, it works OK.
Here is my <kbd>Comment.php</kbd> entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Message cannot be blank" 
 * )     
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "3",
 *      minMessage = "Message must have 3 or more characters"           
 * )     
 */
private $content;
```

In my <kbd>CommentType.php</kbd>

```
// ... namespace and uses
class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            'validation_groups' => (is_null($this->user) ? 'not_logged' : 'Default'), // here I set validation group if user is logged or not
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAction($builder->getAction().'#submit-comment');

        if(is_null($this->user)) {
            $builder->add('author', 'text', array('label' => 'Autor'))
                    ->add('email', 'text', array('label' => 'E-mail (will not show)'))
                    ->add('content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Text',))
                    ->add('captcha', 'captcha', array('invalid_message' => 'Bad captcha', 'background_color' => array(255, 255, 255) )); 
        }        
        else {
            $builder->add('content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Text',));
        }
            $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'submit'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'comment';
    }
}
```

As I wrote, it works correctly (content field) if I'm logged in, but if not, **all** fields are validated **except** content field.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found solution. My problem was here:

```
     'validation_groups' => (is_null($this->user) ? 'not_logged' : 'Default'), // here I set validation group if user is logged or not
```

The problem was that these groups are not in array and **not_logged** group also need **Default** group (it is why it does not work). So working solution is:

```
     'validation_groups' => (is_null($this->user) ? array('Default', 'not_logged') : array('Default')),
```

Thanks for any help and sorry for wasting time on this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not logged, you are using the "not_logged" validation group:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Comment',
    'csrf_protection' => true,
    'validation_groups' => (is_null($this->user) ? 'not_logged' : 'Default'), // here I set validation group if user is logged or not
));
```

but in your entity, there is no information about that group:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "Message cannot be blank",
 *      groups={"not_logged"} // specified group
 * )
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "3",
 *      minMessage = "Message must have 3 or more characters",
 *      groups={"not_logged"}, // specified group
 * )
 */
private $content;
```

Comment: yes because i use this entity validation for logged and not logged users. You didnt understand what I wrote. Only author, mail needs validation group not_logged because logged user will not see this fields. So both kinds of users (logged or not) will have content textarea field

Comment: @apo 'Default' should probably be included as well: groups={"Default", "not_logged"} ? :-)

Comment: @Martin Lie "Default" group cannot be attached to group sequence. Check it at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#book-validation-group-sequence

Comment: @apo But we're not using group *sequences* here anyway?

Comment: i tried to use groups = {"not_logged", "Default"} but same problem.